# Permutation test for equality between the distribution of $g$ population

Tags: statistics, permutations

I have a data matrix of 42000 observation and 12 variables

I suppose to observe 12 samples of size $n_j$ from 12 indipendent random variables $Y_j,j=1,...,g$
I want do a permutation test for $$H_0: Y_1\stackrel{d}=Y_2\stackrel{d}=...\stackrel{d}=Y_{12}\ vs\ H_1: \exists j_1,j_2 \in \{1...g\} \ s.t \ Y_{j1}\neq{Y_{j2}}$$

As test statistics i use Fisher's $$T_F=\frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^g (\overline{Y_j}-\overline{Y})^2/(g-1)}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^g\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_j}({Y_{ij}}-\overline{Y})^2/(n_j-g)}$$
where ${\overline{Y}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^g\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_j}({Y_{ij}})/(n_1+...+n_g)}$ is the common sample mean and $\overline{Y_j}$ is the common sample mean of group $j$.

My main problem is to understand how many permutation i have to do.

I'm not good on permutation test on this amount of data,are there another non-parameetric tests that handle so many observations?

Answer (score 1):

I am puzzled by a few things in your statement of the question:
(a) The denominator of the test statistic $T_F$ does not seem exactly
correct; please check. (b) Are you sampling from your 'data matrix'? If so are the $n_j$ small compared to 42,000?
(c) Why are you using an unbalanced design, potentially with different sample sizes $n_j$ for
the $g$ groups? (d) Are you using a permutation test because you
doubt the data are normal? Because you doubt group variances
are equal?

Therefore, I will show you how to do a permutation test for $g = 3$
groups, each with $n = 20$ replications. I will use $X_{ij} \sim
Norm(100, 15),$ for groups $i = 1$ and $2$ and $X_{3j} \sim
Norm(110, 15).$ Then $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_3$ is false, and
one can check results from a permutation test against a standard
one-factor ANOVA design, where assumptions are met.

**Generate data according to specifications; standard ANOVA rejects at 2% level.**

I hope you can follow the session below in R statistical software.

```
 x1 = rnorm(20, 100, 15);  x2 = rnorm(20, 100, 15);  x3 = rnorm(20, 110, 15)
 x = round(c(x1, x2, x3), 2);  gp = as.factor(rep(1:3, each=20))
 DTA = matrix(x, nrow=3, byrow=T);  DTA  # each row a group of 20
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]
 [1,]  93.32  93.01  98.43 121.13  80.26 103.68 118.07  93.39 106.34 114.47
 [2,] 112.95  91.69  69.57 107.85  87.78 102.45 103.83  99.82 103.31  94.15
 [3,] 123.41 128.82 102.51 123.87 110.34  93.17 117.60 116.67 108.11 110.54
       [,11]  [,12]  [,13]  [,14]  [,15]  [,16]  [,17] [,18]  [,19]  [,20]
 [1,] 115.12 100.76 109.15  83.99 104.52  78.02  94.30 96.52  89.13 105.47
 [2,] 117.33 111.53  85.26 108.22  83.76 103.58 100.22 96.68 109.99 115.83
 [3,] 109.48 102.74 128.30 102.94 124.38  87.74 106.60 94.00  98.90 112.10

 LM = lm(x ~ gp);  anova(LM)
 Analysis of Variance Table

 Response: x
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
 gp         2 1331.5   665.8  4.5547 0.01462   # Signif at 2% level, not 1%
 Residuals 57 8331.8   146.2         

 f.stat.obs = anova(LM)[1,4];  f.stat.obs
 ## 4.554686   # Isolate F-statistic
```

**Perform permutation test, using F-ratio as metric.**
At each iteration, the 60 observations are randomly permuted
and assigned 20 to each group. The F-statistic is computed for
each permutation, thus simulating the permutation distribution of F.

```
 # uses information from code above
 m = 1000;  f.stat.perm = numeric(m)
 for(i in 1:m) {
   x.perm = sample(x, 60)
   f.stat.perm[i] = anova(lm(x.perm ~ gp))[1,4] }
 mean(f.stat.perm >= f.stat.obs)
 ## 0.013
```

The P-value of the simulated permutation test is the proportion
of F-statistics based on permuted data that exceed the F-statistic
for the original (unpermuted) data.

Here the permutation distribution of the F-statistic is very nearly
the same as the distribution of $F(2, 57)$ used in the traditional
one-factor ANOVA (density shown in plot below). This is because the populations are normal and their variances
are the same in all three groups.

```
 hist(f.stat.perm, prob=T, col="skyblue", main="Permutation Dist'n of F-stat")
 curve(df(x,2,57), col="blue", lwd=2, add=T, n=1001)
 abline(v=f.stat.obs, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Even if your data do not meet the requirements for a standard ANOVA
(normal data, homoscedasticity), then the permutation test should
still work. The F-statistic may not have Snedecor's F distribution,
but it is still a reasonable way to measure whether groups
have equal means. The P-value given by the permutation distribution
should provide a fair assessment whether to reject $H_0.$

Here I did only 1000 permutations. For a larger $g$ as you envision, I would use
more iterations (larger `m`). If a couple of successive runs give
about the same P-values, then you are probably doing enough iterations.